# RPi2 Or ODROID-C1 for better OpenCV performance?

Tags: performance, opencv

I am planning for a project requiring face recognition using OpenCV and got confused between two boards at same price - the `Raspberry Pi 2` and `ODROID-C1`.

My question is which board is more suitable (performance wise) for OpenCV implementation?

Comment: When you benchmark both boards against your expected usage it will be interesting to see the results.

Comment: I'm waiting for an answer in this question, my project it's a small web server running tomcat.